# Why should I use command-line arguments?

Tags: c++, c

I've recently learned about command line arguments and I understand how to use them. But I just don't get why I should use them at all. I mean, you could use any normal variable to do the same job as a command line argument.

Could someone explain or give a scenario of how a command line argument could be essential to a program?

Comment: Do you mean a normal variable in the program's source code or an environment variable?

Comment: Can you imagine a program like `ls` (or Windows' `dir`) not accepting command-line arguments?

Comment: `"you could use any normal variable to do the same job as a command line argument"` - You can?  How?

Comment: My teachers have only used command lines to manipulate the program in a similar fashion as a variable, i.e.: displaying the command-line value, mathematical operations, concatenation, etc.

Comment: @Axel1212 *Could someone explain or give a scenario of how a command line argument could be essential to a program?* --  Imagine all the programs that are running on your computer right now that use command-line parameters were to disappear.  Guess what -- you basically would have nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because premise is not clear ("[...] could use any normal variable to do the same job [...]"  - how?)

Comment: @Axel1212: How can you "use a variable" to supply a runtime value to a compiled program?

Comment: When you click on an `mp3` file to play some music, how is the mp3 player going to know what file you clicked on?

Comment: I suppose you have only used an IDE, and never compiled anything on the command line. Imagine what fun it would be to recompile your compiler every time you want to compile a different file.

Comment: You could always use environment variables instead of command-line arguments.  It would be less convenient when working in a console.

Comment: You could also prompt the user for the input instead of the command line arguments however for non-interactive / batch processing of multiple commands command line arguments are the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 13):

```
edit myfile.txt
```

You could always make an editor to edit one specific file, but it would make more sense if the user was able to tell you which file he wanted to edit. Command line args is one way of doing this.

Comment: Unless you're a Gentoo user, in which case you'd compile an optimized binary for the editing task at hand...

Comment: :) from a Gentoo user.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of a command line argument is to allow you to pass information into your program without hard coding it into the program. For example

```
Foo -pages:10
Foo -pages:20
```

Here we've passed information into the program (in this case a `pages` setting). If you set a variable in your program you'd have to recompile it every time you wanted to change it!

Answer (score 5):

It means you don't have to edit the program to change something in it.

Say your program processes all files in a folder to remove icon previews. You could hardcode the folder to process in the program. Or you could specify it as a commandline argument.

I use this example because it describes a bash script I use on my Mac at home.

Answer (score 3):

**Automation**.

You cannot script or use an application/tool in a headless (or unmanned) environment if you require interactive user input.

You can use "config files" and write and read from temporary files, but this can become cumbersome quickly.

**Driving the application**.

Almost every non-trivial application has some variation in what or how it does something; there is some level of control that can and must be applied. Similar to functions, accepting arguments is a natural fit.

The command line is a natural and intuitive environment, supporting and using a command line allows for better and easier adoption of the application (or tool).

A GUI can be used, sure, but unless your plan is to *only* support GUI environments and *only* support input via the GUI, the command line is required.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `echo`, which repeats its arguments—it could hardly work without them.

Or `tar`—how could it tell whether to extract, create, decompress, list, etc. etc. without command line arguments?

Or `git`, with its options to pull, push, merge, branch, checkout, fetch, ...

Or *literally any UNIX program* except maybe `true` and `false` (although the GNU versions of those do take arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

There are countless applications for passing arguments to main. For example, let's say you are a developer and you've designed an application for processing images. Normal users need only to pass the names of the images to your application for processing. The actual source files of your application are not available to them or they are probably not programmers.